# list only directories that contain certain files

Tags: php, arrays, glob, directory

The following code below works fine for listing all directories and excluding those I don't want in the array list, but I'd like to add another feature to be able to ONLY list directories that contain certain files.

For example: Only list directories that contain files:    array('file1.php','file2.php');

```
$exclude = array('admin','inc');        
foreach(glob('./*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
$dir = str_replace('./', '', $dir);
if (!in_array($dir, $exclude))  
{
    //list directories
} }
```

Comment: Are you saying you're unable to keep track of your files ?

Comment: No I'm not saying that, I want to list the directories that contain specific files.

Comment: Use a loop calling `file_exits()`, where the argument is the concatenation of `$dir` and each element of the file array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$exclude = array('admin','inc'); 
$required = array('file1.php', 'file2.php');
foreach(glob('./*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $dir) {
$dir = str_replace('./', '', $dir);
if (!in_array($dir, $exclude))  
{
    foreach($required as $r) {
        if (file_exists("$dir/$r")) {
            echo $dir, "\n";
            break;
        }
    }
} }
```

Comment: Works great, thanks... But had to add missing ) at end of:     if (file_exists("$dir/$r"))